# Force uninstall of the package pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question, but whenever I search force uninstall of pip I get something like a pip uninstall command.  What I want is a way to uninstall the package pip (and reinstall).  when I run `python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools` in a conda enviroment I get this error:

```
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
Found existing installation: setuptools 45.2.0
Not uninstalling setuptools at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'setuptools'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

I also get the same error in the base enviroment when I run `/usr/lib/python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`.
However when I'm outside of a virtual enviroment (base) and I just run `python3 -m pip uninstall pip setuptools`, I get:

```
/home/cameron/anaconda3/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

I could just remove the file but I want to avoid if that would be problematic.

The problematic thing is I can still install things with pip in my base enviroment but I can't call python programs in my virtual enviroments anymore nor install new ones with pip (perhaps able to with conda) since it defaults to the packages installed with this pip even in a venv.

Answer (score 1):

this should remove pip from your active conda environment

```
conda uninstall pip --force
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like this but unfortunately, this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to remove with `sudo apt-get purge python3-pip`